# How can I convert an integer to hex with a fixed length in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, hex, converters

I want to convert an `Integer` to a `hex-string` with a fixed length in JavaScript.

For example I want to convert 154 to hex with a length of 4 digits (`009A`). I can't figure out a proper way to do that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Number.prototype.toString()` can convert a number to hexadecimal when `16` is passed as the argument (base 16):

```
new Number(154).toString(16) //'9A'
```

However, this will not have leading zeroes. If you wish to prepend the leading zeroes you can provide a string of 4 zeroes `'0000'` to concatenate with `'9A'`, then use slice to grab just the last 4 characters:

```
var value = 154;
var hex = ('0000' + value.toString(16).toUpperCase()).slice(-4); //009A
```

The sequence of events is displayed like this:

```
154 -> '9a' -> '9A' -> '00009A' -> '009A'
```

Comment: such a fine solution. Thank you!

Comment: Just a warning with this method -- if your source value is > 65535 (i.e. > 0xFFFF), this will chop significant digits off the front of the result.

Answer (score 5):

You could add some zeroes and use [`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) for the stringed number.

```js
var value = 154,
    string = ('0000' + value.toString(16).toUpperCase()).slice(-4);
    
console.log(string);
```

With [`String#padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

```js
var value = 154,
    string = value.toString(16).toUpperCase().padStart(4, 0);
    
console.log(string);
```

Comment: String#padStart is more reliable because it won't trim large numbers, e.g. value > 0xFFFF in this example.